# Applying a mouseover event listener inside of a loop

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have a button (`<a class="gmButton"></a>`) and a `<span id="gmToolTip"></span>`, and I'd like the `span` to display certain text when the relevant link is mouseovered.

The text to display is an array of strings called `toolTips`.

```
gmButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() { 
        gmToolTip.textContent = toolTips[i];
    }, 500);
});
gmButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    gmToolTip.textContent = null;
    clearTimeout(t);
});
```

When applied to the links one-by-one, the code seems to perform as expected. It's not working when applied in a loop like this. What have I screwed up?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5tpqt5h/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the event listener functions are fired after you have already looped over all of the element. This means that when they are called, `i` is equal to `9` (and `toolTips[9]` is undefined because the last element's index in an array is one less than its `length`).

One option is to wrap the logic in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) in order to capture the current value of `i`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpdj5u62/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < gmButtons.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    gmButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      clearTimeout(t);
      t = setTimeout(function() {
        gmToolTip.textContent = toolTips[i];
      }, 500);
    });
    gmButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
      gmToolTip.textContent = null;
      clearTimeout(t);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

---

Alternately, you could also utilize the [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in order to pass the current value of `i` to the function:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7e97onyt/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < gmButtons.length; i++) {
  gmButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(i) {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() {
      gmToolTip.textContent = toolTips[i];
    }, 500);
  }.bind(this, i));
  gmButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    gmToolTip.textContent = null;
    clearTimeout(t);
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this have to do with lexical scope?

Answer (score 1):

Change `gmTooltip.textContent = null;` to `gmToolTip.textContent = null;`

> gmTool**t**ip to gmTool**T**ip

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, thanks, that was clumsy. It's not the solution though sadly

Answer (score 0):

Try with innerHTML and closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gmButtons.length; i++){
    (function(i) {
      gmButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(function() {
            gmToolTip.innerHTML = toolTips[i];
        }, 500);
    });
    gmButtons[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
        gmTooltip.innerHTML = null;
        clearTimeout(t);
    });
    })(i);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d5tpqt5h/2/)

Comment: Isn't innerHTML a target for XSS?